# I have to create this student data program. There is this warning I just cannot figure out

Tags: c

So I wrote out this code and run it through cygwin terminal! I cleared all the errors but it only leaves me with one last warning I just cannot fix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int phoneNumber;
        char firstName[11];
        char lastName[11];
        char eMail[20];

        printf("Please enter the user's first name:");
        scanf("%s", firstName);
        printf("Please enter the user's last name:");
        scanf("%s", lastName);
        printf("Please enter the user's phone number:");
        scanf("%i", phoneNumber);
        printf("Please enter the user's e-mail:");
        scanf("%s", eMail);
        printf("firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, eMail: %s, %s, %i, %s", firstName, lastName,
phoneNumber, eMail);
}
```

There is the code. The cygwin error tells me:

**warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]**

This refers to the last printf line where the %i is.

Comment: This is c not objective c

Answer (score 1):

Try `scanf("%d", &phoneNumber);` and use `%d` for the `printf` as well.  In C and its derivatives, functions are all pass-by-value.  In order for a function to modify a variable, you need to pass in the address of that variable rather than its value.  That's why you prefix with `&` to get the address of `phoneNumber` into the `scanf` function.  However, you only use the `&` for the `scanf` argument, not for declaring or using the variable locally.

Comment: I voted up your answer, but you might add a little more about what the ampersand is for, for the benefit of OP and other poor souls encountering C and stdio for the first time.

Comment: @Lewis you don't need the ampersand before phoneNumber in the final printf.  That first warning in your screenshot is actually pretty weird though.

Comment: @AaronGolden Yeah. I didn't add the ampersand. This code is just hurting my head. I have no idea what is wrong. I am a beginner as you can see lol.

Comment: @Lewis Are you sure the code you posted is the same that you're compiling? The error message seems to be indicating that the variable `phoneNumber` is an array or other address when you're compiling.

Comment: @pjs Ok I figured it out at the top where it says int phonenumber; I had phonenumber[10]; so it was just me editing the code without pasting the right code here. Sorry about everything!